# Add reference to wcf service to silverlight application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight-4.0

my code is as follows:

```
                ServiceReference1.ImageFile imagefile = new ServiceReference3.ImageFile();
            imagefile.ImageName = fileName;
            imagefile.Imagestream = bytes;

            ServiceReference3.Service1Client service = new ServiceReference3.Service1Client();
            service.UploadCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference3.UploadCompletedEventArgs>(service_UploadCompleted);
            service.UploadAsync(imagefile);
```

here ServiceReference1 is not created how to create service reference and make ServiceReference1 available in xaml.cs page.Anyone helps me is greatly appriciated

Comment: what is problem ...error ????

Comment: i don't make service referece.how to do it?ServiceReference3 or ServiceReference1. make availabe to xaml.cs page.how to create service reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN turotial : [**How to: Access a Service from Silverlight**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197937%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) fir adding service reference

or for web reference

You can do like this check this article for detail : [Add Web Reference to Silverlight Application](http://jkumarsahoo.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/add-web-reference-to-silverlight-application/)

[image]